# JavaScript - constructior inside IIFE

Tags: javascript

Why does the following bit of code not return a Person object?  It instead returns undefined
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HJKa/)

```
var factory = (function () {
        function Person(name, salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        Person.prototype.talk = function () {
            console.log('talking...');
        }
        return {
            Person: Person
        }

    })();
    var x = factory.Person('me', 100);
x.talk(); //cannot read property talk of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BEcause it is not a proper factory :

```
var factory = (function () {
        function Person(name, salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        Person.prototype.talk = function () {
            console.log('talking...');
        }
        return {
            Person: function(name,salary){
              return new Person(name,salary);
            }
        }

    })();
    var x = factory.Person('me', 100);
x.talk(); //cannot read property talk of undefined
```

If you dont call new on Person , there will be no prototypal inheritance.

edit : you can be more abstract on the factory method so you can change the arguments of the constructor without affecting the factory

```
return {
   Person:function(){
        return  new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Person,arguments));
        }
}
```

or make the constructor an impllcit factory

```
       function Person(name, salary) {
            if(!(this instanceof Person)){
              return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Person,arguments));
            }
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`var x = factory.Person('me', 100);` will call `factory.Person()` (which just sets `this.name` and `this.salary` and doesn't return anything, hence `undefined`).

You want to use the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword:

```
var x = new factory.Person('me', 100);
//      ^^^
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HJKa/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate answer already has been posted, however I just wanted to show a different way of achieving the same result by making sure the constructor always returns a new instance of `Person`, even if `new` is forgotten.

```
var factory = (function () {
        function Person(name, salary) {
            if (!(this instanceof Person)) return new Person(name, salary);

            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        Person.prototype.talk = function () {
            console.log('talking...');
        }
        return {
            Person: Person
        }

    })();
    var x = factory.Person('me', 100);
x.talk();
```